# Determine the nature of the series $ \sum_{n \geq 1} u^{\alpha}_n $ with $ u_{n + 1} = \ln(1 + \frac{u_n}{n}) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> We consider the real sequence $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ defined as:
>   $$ 
> \begin{cases}
> u_1 > 0, & \\
> u_{n + 1} = \ln(1 + \frac{u_n}{n}), n \geq 1
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Let $\alpha > 0$. Determine the nature of the series $ \sum_{n \geq 1} u^{\alpha}_n $.

---

We know that: $\forall x > -1: \ln(x + 1) \leq x $

By induction we have $\forall n \geq 1: u_n > 0$

Since: $\dfrac{u_n}{n} + 1 > 0$, we have: $\displaystyle u_{n + 1} = \ln(1 + \frac{u_n}{n}) \leq \frac{u_n}{n}$

By induction we get: 
\begin{align}
&u_{k} \leq \frac{u_1}{(k-1)!} \leq \frac{u_1}{(k-1)} \quad \text{for k} \in \{1, \ldots ,n \} \\
&\implies u_{k}^{\alpha} \leq \frac{u_1^{\alpha}}{(k-1)^{\alpha}} \\
&\implies \sum_{k = 1}^{n} u_{k}^{\alpha} \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{u_1^{\alpha}}{(k - 1)^{\alpha}}
\end{align}

We have: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(k - 1)^{\alpha}} \sim \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}} $, by comparison test, the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{u_1^{\alpha}}{(k-1)^{\alpha}}$ is convergent if $\alpha > 1$.

**Questions**:

**1**. Is the above reasoning correct?

**2**. If $\alpha \leq 1$, how can I determine the nature of the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} u_n^{\alpha}$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic seems correct, but it uses the very weak statement that $(k-1)!\geq k-1$, and much stronger results can be derived using the factorial. Since 
$$u_k\leq \frac{u_1}{(k-1)!},$$
you know that the sum of $u_k^\alpha$ certainly converges if the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!^\alpha}$$
converges. However, $k!>(k/2)^{k/2}$, so
$$k!^\alpha\geq \left(\frac k2\right)^{k\alpha/2}\geq \left(\frac k2\right)^2$$
for large $k$, so the series converges by the comparison test.

Comment: No, I could not finish from there. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi I've added more.

Comment: Accepted answer, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use $n! > (n/e)^{n}$ to get
$u_n < u_1/((n-1)/e)^{n-1}
=u_1(e/(n-1))^{n-1}$
so
$u_n^a < u_1^a(e/(n-1))^{(n-1)a}$
so that
$(u_n^a)^{1/n} < u_1^{a/n}(e/(n-1))^{(1-1/n)a}
\to 0$
for $a > 0$
so
$\sum u_n^a$ converges
for $a > 0$.